# Erro no model em uma página razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho esse cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<TreinamentoCrud.Models.Cidade>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nome)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Quando eu chamo a controller dessa View, tenho esse erro:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

Ou seja, minha model precisa ser instanciada. Como eu faço para funcionar a página?

**EDIT1**

Minha controller(GetCidades) atualmente, mas vou alterar para a sugestão do Netinho

```
public class CidadeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: GetCidade
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetCidades()
        {

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use no seu controller: var model = new List<Cidade>(); Mais para formular melhor uma resposta insira seu controller na pergunta. Esse erro acontece devido sua model está nula

Comment: PNET, faça o curso do Maccoratti: http://www.macoratti.net/curso_aspnet_mvc5_basico.htm ... É barato, é acessivel, está em português.

Answer (score 0):

Faltou fazer o tratamento para ver se já valores no Model, ele está vindo nulo, por isso `NullReferenceException`

Sua `View` pode ser assim:

```
@model IEnumerable<TreinamentoCrud.Models.Cidade>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@if (Model.Count() == 0)
{
    Não há itens cadastrados
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nome)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>


    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nome)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
}
```

Agora antes de iterar ela no `foreach` será verificado se contem valor

Conforme visto pelo @Netinho, é necessário que na sua `Action` retorne o modelo. Na resposta dele, ele trata isso na `Action`, aqui, em outro forma de fazer isso, irei tratar na `View` para exibir uma mensagem caso não tenha itens ainda, sua `Action` ficaria assim:

```
public ActionResult GetCidades()
{
    return View(db.Cidades.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Isso não irá funcionar se ele estiver retornando um null em vez de retornar um enumerable

Comment: Bem visto, não havia me atentado que ele não estava retornando nada.

Answer (score 0):

> Ou seja, minha model precisa ser instanciada. Como eu faço para funcionar a página?

Você pode fazer uma verificação na `Action` se a model está nula, se sim, instancia ela caso contrário retorna sua model.

```
public class CidadeController : Controller
{

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetCidades()
        {
            var model = db.Cidades.ToList();
            return View(model ?? new List<Cidade>());
        }
    }
}
```